# Actionscript 3: Accessing an Instance via String?

Tags: string, oop, actionscript, instance

This is not necessarily specific to ActionScript 3 but I could not think off the top of my head how you would access an instance via string or even if that is possible.

What I have going on is a function in one scene being passed a String which in my case is the name of a particular instance of a movie clip. Is there a way to use that String to access that instance on that scene, IE being passed the string I could change the alpha of that instance which matches the name of the string passed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, it is possible to access all public instances of an object/a scene by doing the following:

```
myMovieClip["myInstance"]
```

This is equivalent to

```
myMovieClip.myInstance
```

So, when you pass a string to a function in order to access a particular instance of that scene, you could, for example, do the following:

```
function myFunc(name:String, alpha:Number):void {
    myMovieClip[name].alpha = alpha;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, I tried doing myMovieClip.StringName at the start but it looked off right off the bat, thanks so much for showing me the other way instead of using the dot operator! you learn something new everyday =p